# how to add value to the existing one via update?

Tags: django

**I have tried the following:**
**how to add value to the existing one via update?**
**view**

```
if test=='' :
  p = models.accounts(date=b,value=a)
  p.save()
else:
    up=models.accounts.objects.filter(date=b).update(value=value+a)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `F()` expression maybe?

F expressions have the advantage of being able to perform database operations without actually having to pull data out of the database. I think Django actually constructs an SQL expression for the given operation and runs at the DB level.

```
from django.db.models import F


up = models.accounts.objects.filter(date=b).update(value=F('value') + some_incremental_value)
```

Comment: When I changed to the code:      
    up=models.accounts.objects.filter(date=b).update(F('value')+a)
I received this massage:  update() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: Thank you very match its done with:      up=models.accounts.objects.filter(date=b).update(value=F('value')+a)

Comment: Ah great! sorry about the error, I'll update my answer accordingly.